# When should you use "erst" rather than "nur"?

Tags: word-choice, adverb

It seems that in many situations where I might use the word *only* in English, either *nur* or *erst* is used in German.  I have the rather fuzzy idea that *erst* is used for *only* in the sense of *something that only happened once* (e.g. *He only went there to see the museum*) whereas *nur* would be used for a general rule (e.g. *She only likes working when it’s raining*).

Even if that’s roughly right, is there more to it than that?  How about something like *I only have two biscuits left*?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Erst** is used to describe a temporal order, i.e. to denote that something happens first, and something else afterwards.

A second usage pattern of **erst** is indeed close to **only**, in cases where it is used to show that **so far**, something has happened not very often, but this is intended to be changed.

Your examples:

- He only went there to see the museum. - Er fuhr nur hin, um das Museum zu sehen/besuchen. *OR* Er fuhr erst dann hin, als er das Museum besuchen konnte. (Here, we have introduced a temporal order: only when the museum was open and he was able to visit it, he went there.)
- She only likes working when it's raining. - Sie mag ihre Arbeit nur, wenn es regnet. *OR* Sie mag ihre Arbeit erst dann, wenn es regnet. (Temporal order again: Only when it rains, she is able to enjoy her work.)
- I only have two biscuits left. - Ich habe nur zwei Kekse übrig. (no temporal order possible here)
- Er konnte Klavier spielen, als er erst sechs Jahre alt war. - This sentence sounds a bit unusual to me and I would have to stop and think about your usage of "erst", but in the end I think you would be understood. I would rephrase it though:

  - "Er konnte bereits mit sechs Jahren Klavier spielen." - not use "erst" or "nur" at all
  - "Er spielte mit nur sechs Jahren bereits Klavier."
  - "Er war erst sechs Jahre alt und konnte bereits Klavier spielen."

Some more examples:

- Ich war erst einmal in Berlin. - So far, I have visited Berlin only once.
- Erst war ich in Berlin, dann in Hamburg. - Temporal order: I visited Berlin first, then I went to Hamburg.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and examples.  As a followup, could you confirm whether a sentence like "er konnte Klavier spielen, als er erst sechs Jahre alt war" also fits the temporal order usage pattern?  I interpret it to mean "only, but also after" - so it's similar but the "erst" marks the start rather than the end of something in time.

Comment: In that context, you can also use "nur", because it's not necessarily temporal. "Mozart war nur drei Jahre alt, als er seine ersten Konzerte gab". "Mozart war erst drei Jahre alt ...." Both work, although "erst" sounds more familiar. Maybe because the reference to age supports the notion of a temporal context.

Comment: I think the age reference is the only one where you can really use "erst" and "nur" interchangeably: In one case you refer to  the small amount of time and in the other case it's the low value of the number.... which both ends up meaning the exact same thing...

Comment: @Jan: How about "Er konnte *schon* Klavier spielen, als er erst sechs Jahre alt war" - sounds better/more fluent, doesn't it?

Comment: @Oliver yes, that would make it more readable to me...

Comment: @Jan I would have always said "Ich war *nur* einmal in Berlin".  Should I take it from your answer that this is incorrect?

Comment: @Glen: "Ich war *nur* einmal in Berlin" is also correct, but conveys a different meaning from "ich war *erst* einmal in Berlin". With the former, you're saying that you only have been there once and don't make any statement about your intentions to return. With the latter, you regret that you've been there only once *yet* and state your intention to return.

Comment: @Jan Thank you very much.  This kind of implied meaning is very hard to learn.  You're a champ!

Comment: @Glen yeah, sorry about that ;-) As they say, "Deutsche Sprache, schwere Sprache..."

Comment: In the "erst" usage description, I read "something has happened not very often, but this is intended to be changed." . This reference to periodicity confused me. Repetition and periodicity are very different concepts. I thought that "erst" referred to the former? In other words, I'd expected to read "something has happened a number of times, but it is intended to happen again". Could someone clarify?

Answer (score 7):

With *nur* one points to the state in which things are; with *erst* the emphasis lies on the point when things change or the progress in general.

> Ich habe *nur* zwei Kekse übrig. — I only have two biscuits left and their amount is not going to increase.
>
> Ich habe *erst* zwei Kekse übrig. — I only have two biscuits left but I’m expecting to get more of them.

The second phrase is a bit strange, of course, since the Word *übrig* denotes that one indeed does *not* expect any new biscuits.

> Sie mag ihre Arbeit *nur*, wenn es regnet. — She only likes her work when it’s raining.
>
> Sie mag ihre Arbeit *erst*, wenn es regnet. — Emphasises that it needs to *start* raining.

Two more examples:

> Mozart war *nur* drei Jahre alt, als er seine ersten Konzerte gab. — Sounds a bit contrived because one expects ageing to be a progress and therefore saying *nur* is strange. It would work, if he *stopped* ageing afterwards or if he’d always been three years old. Or if the young age were simply an additional fact but nothing which made it even more important.
>
> Mozart war *erst* drei Jahre alt, als er seine ersten Konzerte gab. — Emphasises that it was a young age and even though he was still getting older, he did not wait until then.
>   (Consider Mozart had been shot at the age of three – then one would have to say *nur* in order to emphasise his young age but using *erst* would not work since his age does not have any further influence on the fact that he had been shot.)
>
> *Nur* auf der Zielgeraden konnte er den Läufer einholen. — Emphasises where he could catch the runner: only on the home stretch. (And they might have run 1500 m and so he had the chance a couple of times.)
>
> *Erst* auf der Zielgeraden konnte er den Läufer einholen. — Emphasises that he tried but could not do it until on the home stretch.

Note that in the last two examples the meaning is somewhat inverted. In the Mozart example *erst* means that something good happened very early in the process (of aging). In the sports example it means that it happened rather late. (One could reverse both examples with the word *schon*/‘already’.)

> Ich war *nur* einmal in Berlin. — More of a simple fact. I know it’s a small number (one) 
>   but that’s just how it is.
>
> Ich war *erst* einmal in Berlin. — More of a personal statement. I know it’s a small number and I might change it, if I could and if I really wanted to do it. (However, it does not say that one wants to get there another time. It is only possible that one does.)

Comment: The sentence "Ich habe erst zwei Kekse übrig" is more than _a bit_ strange - it sounds just wrong. But the rain example is very nice!

Comment: True. But in a way that is what helps explaining the whole thing. In most cases, *übrig* means that a certain amount might *not* increase anymore, whereas *erst* means it might. Still, too me it sounds like there might be a situation in which one might just be able to say it that way.

Comment: @Debilki: OK, I see. Still, you might want to make it clearer that one shouldn't go and try to use the contrived sentences if one doesn't know _exactly_ what one's doing. Nevertheless, have a +1 for the rain from me.

Comment: The cookie example actually would make sense in a situation where someone habitually eats a whole box of cookies and is now on a diet: When reporting on their progress, they might say "Ich habe (dieses Mal) erst zwei Kekse übrig" - implying that on their next cookie binge they hope to be able to stop earlier, leaving more cookies in the box.

Answer (score 2):

I totally agree with the temporal order. The examples are good, +1 for the *rain — work* one. There is another semantic aspect when using *erst* and *nur* — the implication of *expectation* or *disappointment*. Maybe a modified cookie example is good to explain what i mean:

Someone promises me three cookies before some other action.

> Ich hatte erst zwei Kekse. / I only had two cookies yet.

This implies that cookies are still available and time is left. Give me my third cookie! :)

> Ich hatte nur zwei Kekse. / I only had two cookies.

This implies that there are no cookies left or time is up and I didn’t get three cookies as promised. :,(

The sentence “I only have two biscuits left” is translated with *nur* e.g. if there are more people than biscuits and people have to share what’s left.

If there are more biscuits than people and you want to get rid of your biscuits (Take one!) you would use *noch* (“Ich habe noch zwei Kekse übrig.”)

If you collect bisuits and want let’s say five pieces and still need two more, you use *erst*: “Ich habe erst drei Stück, ich benötige noch zwei.”

Answer (score 1):

"Nur" means "only." Wir sind nur Erwachsende hier. Or, "He only went there to see the museum" (and nothing else).

"Erst" means "only when." Erst A, dann B.Or, "She likes working *only when* it’s raining."